# How to count words in multiple strings with same class and if amount of words equals a specific value, replace white space with a break tag?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have multiple strings with the same class and am counting the amount of words per string with the .each function.  When the amount of words equals 2, I want to replace the white space with a break tag.  There is a fiddle below.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="navoption">The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</a><br /><br />
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="navoption">Quick brown.</a><br /><br />
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="navoption">The quick brown fox jumps.</a><br /><br />
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="navoption">Lazy dog.</a><br /><br />
<button class="break">Wrap Two Words</button>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button.break').click(function(){
        $.each($('.navoption'), function() {
            var count = $(this).text().split(" ");
            var amount = count.length;
            if (amount == 2) {
                $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/ /g, "<br />"));
            } 
            else {
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ut60pyff/

EXPECTED RESULT:

The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.

Quick
brown.

The quick brown fox jumps.

Lazy
dog.

Comment: what is your question or what error you get?

Comment: There is no error. I am attempting to find which strings contain ONLY two words and replace the white space with a break tag in only those.

Comment: Right now it isn't doing anything.  I checked by alerting the amount values and it shows the number of words but the function of replacing the white space with a break tag in ONLY the ones with two words isn't working.

Comment: Added HTML. Searching each individual string to count amount of words, if amount equals ONLY 2, then replace white space with break tag.  Otherwise do nothing.

Comment: Just did, sorry, first time using this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change to:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".break").click(function(){
        $(".navoption").each(function(){
        var count = $(this).text().split(" ");
            var amount = count.length;
            if (amount == 2) {
                $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/ /g, "<br />"));
            } 
        });

    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/osmanrahimi/yhd48npv/

Answer (score 1):

When you return `false` from inside the loop, you end the loop. If the callback for the `$.each` method returns `false`, the loop is terminated.

So, you only need to remove the `return false;` to make the code work.

However, you can use the `html` method to easily change the content of each of the elements. You get the current HTML code as a parameter, and return what you want it to be:

```
$('.navoption').html(function (i, h) {
  if (h.split(" ").length == 2) {
    h = h.replace(/ /g, "<br />");
  }
  return h;
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ut60pyff/3/

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
$('button.break').click(function() {
    $.each($('.navoption'), function() {
        var word_arr = $(this).text().split(" ");
        if (word_arr.length === 2) {
            $(this).html(word_arr.join("<br/>"));
        }
    });
});
```